# Invoke method of non-referenced assembly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, events, delegates, assemblies

I'm trying to setup a modular MVC4 project.

Right now, the webapplication has a reference to a "Core" assembly. My modules are in the core. A module has the required controllers and views. So, my Views and controllers are in a seperate project. Using a custom viewengine to render it. So far so good..

However, i would like to split the Modules from the core assembly itself. Thus being able to 'inject' my modules from a different project.

Right now, the 'core' is (also) responsible for creating all the navigation properties for the webapp, wrapped in a navigation class like so:

```
public static List<IModuleNavigationGroup> CRM() {
  var NavigationGroups = new List<IModuleNavigationGroup>();
  NavigationGroups.Add(Modules.ServiceDesk.Navigation.MenuItems());
  NavigationGroups.Add(Modules.Relation.Navigation.MenuItems());
  NavigationGroups.Add(Modules.Invoices.Navigation.MenuItems());
  NavigationGroups.Add(Modules.Projects.Navigation.MenuItems());
  return NavigationGroups;
}
```

This works, but i don't want to have this "CRM" method for making a navigation menu from within the core. Instead, I need/want to create a new project, reference the core and subscribe to an initialize method (or something). When this method is invoked i want to add the navigation from the modules to the core navigation.

My idea was the following

The following 2 are always needed:

> project 1 - Core
>
> project 2 - Presentation (UI)

The 'optional' project, or the one housing the modules

> project 3 - Modules

Now, when (2) is started it will initialize the navigation from (1). When this happens, (1) must know which items to return from (3). I don't want a reference from (1) to (2 or 3) because in a different project the modules might differ.

I was thinking about delegates from (1) but (3) is never instantiated.

Thanks in advance, i hope my question is clear.

Comment: You can use a DI or IOC framework. Basic steps: 1) define interfaces so you know how to communicate with these modules. 2) use Assembly.Load to load your modules at runtime. 3) Register the object which implement the interfaces at a factory. 4) Request the modules at your factory and you're done.

Comment: Step 2 is what i cannot do in the core project, because i don't know which assembly will be used. The navigation groups all implement an INavigationGroup interface. Might there be a way to find all classes implementing this interface without knowing the assembly at runtime?

Comment: `Might there be a way to find all classes implementing this interface without knowing the assembly at runtime?` Without knowing the assembly @ runtime? That's hard. If I would create an assembly with your interface you can never tell. Without knowing the assembly @ buildtime is not a problem. You can load the assemblies at runtime (maybe from a plugin folder) an inspect the classes if they implement your `INavigationGroup` interface.

Comment: By the way; you'll need a different approach for the `NavigationGroups.Add(Modules.Relation.Navigation.MenuItems())`. If you want a dynamic setup you are only allowed to talk with the interfaces, not the concretes.